# Rename RedHat7 hostname without reboot

Tags: rhel, hostname

How do I rename the RedHat7 hostname without a reboot? I am also trying to automate this task.

Comment: I tried the solution below and it just worked great on my Debian Jessie :).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
[root@stephan ~]# echo stephan2 > /etc/hostname # this is the file that your system reads on boot, to determine the hostname
[root@stephan ~]# sed -i s/stephan/stephan2/g /etc/hosts # many networking headaches will ensue if this isn't updated
[root@stephan ~]# hostname -F /etc/hostname # reread the hostname file to update the systems hostname.
```

Your prompt will continue to display the old hostname until you log out of it and back in, or execute a new shell session.

```
[root@stephan ~]# logout
[stephan@stephan ~]$ sudo su -
Last login: Wed Sep 28 18:06:35 EDT 2016 on pts/0
[root@stephan2 ~]#
```

Comment: what is "s/stephan/stephan2/g"? Thanks.

Comment: 'sed' is the stream text editor.  It's a command that changes text in place, either from a stream of text you 'pipe' into it, or occurrences of that text in a file.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed

Answer (score 2):

Use the following command to change the hostname on RHEL7:

```
hostnamectl set-hostname name
```

To view current hostnames:

```
hostnamectl status
```

Refer to the [Red Hat Enterprise Linux Networking](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Networking_Guide/sec_Configuring_Host_Names_Using_hostnamectl.html) guide for further details.